# Analogue of NP for oracle problems

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, np, oracle-machines, polynomial-time-reductions

I was just reading [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/what-is-the-complexity-of-hidden-subgroup-problems) question on the quantum computation stack exchange. It asks whether the HSP is in NP or not, and the answer notes that NP is a class of languages, not oracle problems.

The answer then goes on to mention the at a special case of the HSP, where the mapping is a group homomorphism is in this oracle variant of NP. But what is this “oracle NP?”

For example, what is an Oracle-NP complete problem? Is SAT Oracle NP-complete, or is Oracle based quantum search Oracle NP-Complete?

Comment: That answer does not contain the phrase "oracle NP", so I'm not sure what you are quoting.  The question explains what it means, in the very next sentence: "In other words, we can ask..."; if that doesn't answer your question, I encourage you to [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking and what your understanding is and the motivation for asking. I encourage you to [edit] your question to spell out what the acronym HSP refers to, to help others with a similar question find this page via web search.